# How to control speed of audio in Media Element in Window Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am playing audio with media element by converting text to speech in my app.
here is my code

```
var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            var voice=SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices;
            synth.Voice = voice[2];
 var text = "My name is John";

            var stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);

            var me = new MediaElement();
             me.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
            me.Play();
```

Audio here being played is fast .I want that audio should play slowly. I tried Playback property of media element but its does not work.How to control speed of play back in media element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DefaultPlaybackRate` property:

```
var me = new MediaElement();
me.DefaultPlaybackRate = 0.5;
me.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
me.Play();
```

You can also use `PlaybackRate` property if you don't want it to persist throughout the lifetime of the `MediaElement`. This happens because `PlaybackRate` will have `DefaultPlaybackRate` value when `Play` method is called till playback ends.

[**Reference**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.defaultplaybackrate.aspx)

Comment: thanks a lot. One more thing in my above code i select voice with index no this is not a good technique ,how can i correct this.

Comment: you should check for voice availability using something like: `if(SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.Count > 0) { //play... }` or it might throw an exception and crash your application. Then choose one of them or ask the user which one wants. Don't forget to accept the answer. Users that don't accept answers to their questions receive less answers from other users.

Comment: every Operating system has two voices builtin 1.Male 2.Female is it right?

Comment: it might have more male or female voices installed. Use `Voice.DisplayName` to identify each. If I were you I would use OS predefined voice using: `SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice`

Comment: Yes but I am developing kids application so i want voice like kids . Sorry but question arising again n again ,Can i change voice rate,pitch or frequency to make voice like kids?

Comment: No. You can try to install a kids voice but I don't know if that exists.